# Find out in an array of numbers if any number is close to any of the numbers in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array of different whole numbers like so `[46, 18, 49, 15]` what i want to know if there is any number that is close to any of the other numbers in this case there aren't any so the function have to return false, but if there are for example `[14, 31, 13, 40, 30]` 30 and 31 are close and 14 and 13 to each others so the function have to return true. 
thanks!

Comment: please define *close*, is it just the delta of one?

Comment: 30 and 31 are close, but 15 and 16 and 13 and 14 aren't...?!

Comment: Sort the array and check if adjacent pairs are "close".

Comment: thanks all for the comments i made a mistake and i fixed it now :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sort it and check the delta.

```js
function close(a) {
    a.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
    return a.some(function (b, i, aa) {
        return i && b - aa[i - 1] <= 1;
    });
}

document.write(close([14, 31, 13, 40, 30])+'<br>');
document.write(close([46, 18, 49, 15]) + '<br>');
```

Answer (score 4):

Sort the numbers. Then loop through the numbers and for each number see if this number is equal to the next number minus 1. If that is true, return `true`. Otherwise, if you finished the loop, return `false`.

Comment: _this number is equal to the next number minus 1_......or **this number+1 is equal to the next number**.....+1 though for answering this question where OP has not tried anything.